# AWS Kinesis Data Analytics (Apache Flink java app) crashing randomly on Kinesis inputstream RuntimeException

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have three different Apache Flink applications running on 3 different AWS kinesis data analytics which are consuming data from the same kinesis input stream. After a while I can see all the flink randomly crashed and restarts with the error messages. I am not sure what is the rootcause of the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.: Retries exceeded for getRecords operation - all 3 retry attempts failed.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getRecords(KinesisProxy.java:317)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisher.getRecords(PollingRecordPublisher.java:168)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisher.run(PollingRecordPublisher.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.publisher.polling.PollingRecordPublisher.run(PollingRecordPublisher.java:102)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.run(ShardConsumer.java:114)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of the Kinesis Data stream? Since you have 3 consumers on the stream, you need to make sure it is provisioned for it. Start by checking this metric "Read throughput exceeded - average (Percent)
" for the Stream in the Monitoring section.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes the source was throttling.